# Can I delete all sqlite databases by a button in storage device?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

I have set two buttons in my notes app  , one is for creating Backups and the other one is for importing the backups which I created previously .

All my backups go to this file by the database name in storage device (note.db)

[image]

So I would like when the user import the wanting backup , so there will be a button as well which he/she be able to delete all other unwanted backups inside the storage device.

Thank you very much for helping :)

Comment: If think you can with `this.databasList();` and `deleteDatabase("name");`

Comment: Can you explain more ? Do i have to add that code in  @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // update database for database version < 2
        if (oldVersion < 2) {
            db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE " + TABLE_NOTE + " ADD COLUMN " + KEY_LAST_MODIFIED_NOTE + " TEXT DEFAULT \'\'");
        }
    }

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want to try. You want to delete all you database ?
So i think you can do that :

```
for (String tmp : this.databaseList()){
    this.deleteDatabase(tmp)
}
```

Comment: Where do you want, in `onClick()`, for when you pressed a button, if you do that, remove `this.`

Comment: Just curious. What class is `this`? There is no code in the question that has either of these methods

Comment: `this` is related to your `MainActivity`